# "Unmet dependencies" for kernel and other packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

When I try to install some package, I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-39-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-cleaner : Depends: python-defer but it is not installable
                  Depends: python-lxml but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-dbus but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-aptdaemon but it is not installable
                  Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**UPD:** result of - `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common gyp javascript-common libaio1 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libevent-core-2.0-5 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid libjs-sphinxdoc
  libjs-underscore liblua5.1-0 libmcrypt4 libssl-dev libssl-doc libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-38 linux-headers-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-38 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-39 linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-39-generic python-pkg-resources
  zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-tools linux-hwe-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 400 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/70,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 228 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 465767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic (4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.15.0-43-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.15.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic (4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic_4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Examining /etc/kernel/preinst.d/
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/preinst.d/intel-microcode 4.13.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic (4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic_4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.13.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.13.0-45-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-45-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic_4.15.0-38.41~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic_4.15.0-38.41~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic (4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.15.0-39-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.15.0-39-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic (4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-39-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic_4.13.0-45.50~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-38-generic_4.15.0-38.41~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic_4.15.0-39.42~16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**UPD2:**  result of - `df -h`

```
226M  220M     0 100% /boot
```

result of - `du -h --max-depth=1 /boot`

```
120M    /boot/.Trash-0
6,8M    /boot/grub
12K     /boot/lost+found
218M    /boot
```

But if I open folder properties in nautilus, I see a different size

> 307 items, totalling 102,2 MB (some contents unreadable)

result of `ls` - `total 93009`

**UPD3:** All commands with `apt`, `apt-get` or `dpkg`) give these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.15.0-38 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: @Melebius Yes, i tried it

Comment: Looks like you are out of space as [KSI noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108840/250300). If you have a separate boot partition, check https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to.

Comment: Hope [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104845/ubuntu-16-04-cant-install-any-software/1104847#1104847) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems out of space.

- **So first confirm this.**
- Run for all **Ubuntu partitions** e.g. "/" "/boot" etc.

  ```
  df -h /
  df -h /boot
  df -h /<other-partions-if-any>
  ```
- **To make space in "/boot" partition.**
- To check extra kernels. Run in terminal.

  ```
  apt --dry-run purge $(dpkg -l|egrep 'linux-image-[0-9]|linux-headers-[0-9]'|awk '{print $3,$2}'|grep -v `uname -r|cut -f1,2 -d"-"`|sort -nr|tail -n +4|awk '{ print $2}')
  ```
- If ok then remove all but latest two kernel. Run in terminal.

  ```
  sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l|egrep 'linux-image-[0-9]|linux-headers-[0-9]'|awk '{print $3,$2}'|grep -v `uname -r|cut -f1,2 -d"-"`|sort -nr|tail -n +4|awk '{ print $2}')
  ```
- If that is not possible and /boot is full, remove some config* files by
- ***CAUTION: Do not remove any file related to the two latest kernels.***

  `sudo rm /boot/<file-name>` of old kernels or even some vimlinuz* files.
- After you have solved the problem run in terminal.

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove
  ```
- **To make space in "/" partition.**
- To remove unwanted pakages. Run in terminal.

  ```
  sudo apt autoremove
  ```
- To remove all .deb file in apt cache. Run in terminal.

  ```
  sudo apt clean
  ```
- To remove old config files. Run in terminal.

  ```
  dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt purge -y
  ```
- To empty every trash. Run in terminal.

  ```
  rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
  sudo rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
  ```
- To remove extra kernels. Run in terminal.

  ```
   sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l|egrep 'linux-image-[0-9]|linux-headers-[0-9]'|awk '{print $3,$2}'|grep -v `uname -r|cut -f1,2 -d"-"`|sort -nr|tail -n +4|awk '{ print $2}')
  ```
- To remove orphaned packages. Run in terminal.

  ```
  sudo apt install deborphan
  sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt -y remove --purge
  ```
- Move some saved video audio or other personal data files from /home to some other partition.

Comment: UPD3, look please

Answer (score 1):

You're just running  our of space.
It looks like your disk is full as per log.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.15.0-43-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.15.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': **failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error**
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic_4.15.0-43.46~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...

You can try deleting no more needed files and/or backing up any media content on a cloud service to free space.

**edit**
suggested to edit . 
I used the following ways to clean up the extra packages and free up space
as mentioned @ https://askubuntu.com/a/205776/599385

Answer (score -1):

You need to free some space. You should check your /boot partition/folder, is it possible to make it bigger? Can you post the output `sudo df -h` and `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /boot`?

After seeing the output of.du command, you can see that you have a .Trash folder (do you deleted something with nautilus maybe?) inside /boot. Try deleting it and doing the apt and dpkg commands after that

Comment: UPD2, look please

Comment: This does provides an answer ("free some space").

Comment: The clarification was necessary.

Comment: @Sergey did you fixed this issue? have you tried to delete .Trash-0 folder??